# Apache Kylin: query returns error 'null'

Tags: apache, kylin

I started using Apache kylin (version 1.5.3) and have some problems with an easy query.

The query

```
select ft.sid, count(ft.sid) as cs
from (
        select sid, lid
        from ft_demo 
        group by lid, sid
     ) as ft inner join (
        select lid
        from lt_demo
        where abc = '01234'
     ) as lt on (ft.lid = lt.lid)
group by ft.sid
having (count(ft.sid) > 1);
```

returns the error

> Error while executing SQL "select ft.sid, count(ft.sid) as cs from (select sid, lid from ft_demo group by lid, sid) as ft inner join (select lid from lt_demo where abc = '01234') as lt on (ft.lid = lt.lid) group by ft.sid having (count(ft.sid) > 1) LIMIT 50000": null

Submitting a shorter version works. Like

```
select ft.sid
from (
        select sid, lid
        from ft_demo 
        group by lid, sid
     ) as ft inner join (
        select lid
        from lt_demo
        where abc = '01234'
     ) as lt on (ft.lid = lt.lid);
```

returns a list of of sid's where some appear more than once. So, all I want to get with the first query is a list of sid's appearing more than once and their occurrence.

The query is working fine in Apache hive. Does anyone know, why kylin is not able to submit the query and returns null?

Comment: Need the complete log for troubleshooting. Also this looks like a defeat that should be reported to Kylin community.

Answer (score -1):

if you have any date columns, enter date lesser than column date in partition start date under refresh setting while building the cube.

Comment: Ok. Then check the whether the fact table you have loaded has data in it. Are you getting the table names to the left of your screen under Insight tab. Seems to be problem with your cube.

Comment: the cube seems to be alright. other queries work, like the one mentioned in the post above. basically its the 'group by' and 'count' which seems to cause an error when used on an result of an join. but I dont know why...